# Issue on Destroying - Ending Session on Logout

Tags: php, session

I have a session set up like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass =  $_POST['pass'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM tempusers WHERE user='$email' AND pass='$pass'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
 $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 if( $num_row >=1 ) {
  echo 'true';
     $_SESSION['uName'] = $row['uName'];
  }
 else{
  echo 'false';
 }
?>
```

and in my logout.php I have

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset(); 
    unset($_SESSION['uName']);
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

but none of the `session_unset();` , `unset()` and `session_destroy();` seems to be not working because after getting to the page I am still able to use browser Back button and back to the restricted page! besides the `header()` is not changing the page into `index.php` can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Basically, I have a Log out Link in Restricted page which is like this

```
<a href="logout.php" >Logout</a>
```

Thanks

Update:
Here is the Session code which I have at the top of restricted page

```
<?php
 session_start();
  if(empty($_SESSION['uName'])){
     header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: If you go back to the page where it goes in the DB and authorises you (presuming POST is resent) then the IF will be TRUE, and the session set again.

Comment: Thanks James but I didnt get what exactly you mean?

Comment: Your question isn't perfectly clear regards your login flow, I meant: You POST form data to script above, you get logged in as credentials correct, session is set, you go to next page now logged in, you click logout, you are logged out, you click back, the POST data is still set and checks data in the DB returns TRUE again (as POST data did before), your session is created again.  - What do you get if at the end of logout.php file you echo out your session (and use `exit()` after the echo)? Is it still set?

Comment: Thanks James I got it and it is exactly my issue , but how I can fix it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get - Stack has some good answers on Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Ok I update the logout code by adding `$_POST = array();` to empty the Post data but still same issue!

Comment: Hey man, sounds kinda like your page isn't checking against a session property properly... I'd start by posting your validation code (whatever you're using to ensure a user is logged in). Also, I run a print_r($_SESSION). Just create a new page on your server, with <?php session_start(); print_r($_SESSION);?> This will show you what properties you have within your session. I had this issue at one point and realized I was checking against the wrong thing when verifying my user was logged in. :S

Comment: Hi Ethan thanks for reply I have updated to post with adding the secession part of the app.php which is the page that is supposed to be restricted. Can you please take a look at that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try regenerating the session id and destroying all the data.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', 0, '/');
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: Hi slapyo , thanks for reply but I am still getting same result

Comment: Does the redirect work? There is no white space before the opening PHP tag or the session_start() function right?

Comment: No , I just copied all you have gave but everything is same!